# Red numbers in DF stock overview?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

To get an overview of my stocks, I can go to Status (z) - Stocks. There, I see the amounts of most goods, but I also see some numbers in red. Some are smaller and some are larger than the amount I have. What do the red numbers mean?

Comment: Seems to be related to forbidden items or items in workshops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The red numbers denote the total number of restricted items in that category - items on the map that are not owned by the fort (i.e. traders or invaders), uncollected items (such as webs), items used in construction (such as blocks or buckets), or items that are designated as forbidden or queued to be melted.